# OpenCL work item ordering

Tags: opencl, gpu, cpu, nvidia, atomic

With OpenCL 1.1, is it possible to force work items to order their execution so they wait until higher priority items have finished?

I've tried various implementations and seem to always get stuck when executing my kernel on a GPU (Nvidia OpenCL 1.1); although running on a CPU is fine.

My most recent attempt below will hang on a GPU. My suspicion is that the GPU is splitting the global work group in local groups that get suspended creating a deadlock. I typically run a global size several multiples of my local size and this is important for scaling up my calculation.

```
kernel void ordered_workitem_kernel(
    global uint *min_active_id_g
) {
    uint i = get_global_id(0);
    min_active_id_g[0] = 0;
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    while (i >= min_active_id_g[0]) {

        // do something interesting here

        if (i == min_active_id_g[0])
            atomic_inc(&min_active_id_g[0]);
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's a better way to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no order in the work items execution. And there is also no way to force it. Otherwise you are completely breaking the purpose of parallel system. Basically you have a non-parallelizable algorithm, and you are telling the OpenCL: "Run everything at the same time, but run it in order".

Comment: Do higher priority items change other items' inputs ? Maybe your algorithm is scannable into a parallel version?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes they do. In the sense, that each thread has works on part of a global block of data it is responsible for. Another thread can atomically add to that data. I know I can create an work item ordering by simply calling atomic_inc on a global index variable but that won't pause the other work items.

Comment: The other thing you need to realize is that not all work items are being processed at once. The runtime may fully execute a subset of work items fully, and then do another batch, etc. until the entire global size is done. So you can't wait in one work item waiting for a work item that isn't even executing yet.